# try if I like it

Tags: vocabulary

"I'd like to live for a longer time in the States. I'm going there next week for a few days. This will be a good opportunity to try if I like it."

Someone said to me this "try if" and it doesn't sit right with me. I would expect there to be something like "check" or "check out if I like it".

How about you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of saying this, but, "**try if I like it**" isn't one of them. Your friend is right. I think most native speakers would say "This will be a good opportunity **to see if I like it**" as the closest to your sentence. Or as Lambie says in their comment "This will be a good opportunity **to try it out and see if I like it**" Your version
"This will be a good opportunity **to check it out**" is another valid option.
Other colloquialisms include **to test the waters** and **to wet my toe(s)**.

Comment: to try it out and see if I like it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: So "check if I like it" sounds bad?

Comment: @ASDASDASDASD No, "check if I like it" is perfectly good English and would be understood without any problem by any native English speaker. It's just that, where I come from (Southern England) "see" is a more common way of saying it.